# How can get detected object bounding box coordinates in ssd_pascal_video.py

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

In caffe-ssd, specifically speaking，my object is to print the output bbox coordinates in the py script（ssd_pascal_video.py）,but I can't do that and I feel puzzled.

In **bbox_util.cpp** and **detection.ipynb**, I can see the code about bbox, but I didn't know how to get coordinates in py scripts. For example, the bbox coordinates is xmin,xmax,ymin and ymax, but how to use it in py scripts? May I need to write some similar code about bbox from **bbox_util.cpp**? Is there any methods or suggestions?

In conclusion:

1. I didn't know how to get detected object bounding box coordinates in ssd_pascal_video.py
2. I want to get a log file to save the right bounding box coordinates.
3. I tried many times,and I found it seems that I should write some calculation bbox code in py scripts from bbox_util.cpp, because the bbox coordinates is mentioned in bbox_util.cpp.
   That's all my understanding, but I didn't get the result. Thank you for attention!

Comment: please elaborate. it is unclear what you are trying to do and what your problem is.

Comment: @Shai Sorry, I'd like to get the detected bbox coordinates in ssd_pascal_video.py, but I don't konw how to use the xmin,xmax,ymin and ymax in py scripts,do you understand?

Comment: your question is still not clear: you edit your post, yet put some of the question in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016514/is-there-any-good-methods-to-use-bounding-box-coordinates-in-ssd-pascal-video-py?noredirect=1#comment75060880_44016514)... Try to look at your post with "fresh eyes": can you understand what is going on? pasting tons of code does not make the question clearer: Are you expecting code review? Please go over [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help pages, and try to edit your question accordingly. **Good questions usually get good answers**

Comment: @Shai Sorry,I'm not good at programming, wish this time  the problem is clear.

Comment: you don't need to be good at programming: this is what SO is for ;) you need to be good at asking.

Comment: @Shai  Thank you! So how can I get detected object bounding box coordinates in ssd_pascal_video.py?

Comment: your question is still unclear. Please write (1) what you are executing at the moment (don't link to code, don't post tens of lines, we are not code reviewers here). (2) what result do you currently have. (3) **why** the current result is not good (4) what result would you rather get instead.

Comment: @Shai  well, thanks, I'm sorry for that. Is it clear now?

Comment: much better. I don't know `'ssd_pascal_video.py'`, I know caffe and python. Can you say what caffe commands you are running? `forward` pass? `backward`? what are the net outputs you actually have? and why these outputs are not the bbox you expect?

Comment: is it possible you do not see any logged output because of the `"Silence"` layer [(line 266-7)](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_video.py#L266)?

Comment: @Shai  Well, I think the ssd_pascal_video.py is a script to test one trained model in python, the output information is just a window named "detection", which is defined in bbox_util.cpp. Of course, the bbox is contained in a parameter named "variance",which used to  encode/decode prior bboxes. The result is good, but I want get not only the "detection" window, but also the bbox coordinates.

Comment: @Shai I tried it just now as you mentioned, it is a detection_out information, like the score of bbox, not the coordinates.

Comment: AFAIK `detection_out` outputs 7 numbers per detection, it's confidence, detection class, 4 coordinates (and one more number I don't really know).

Comment: @Shai  Well, it actually showed 7 numbers, but why the most number are all decimal range from 0 to 1, it is coordinates ? From where I can see the detection_out definition?

Comment: the output BBox are relative to image size, you need to multiply by image height and width (respectively).

Comment: @Shai  sure? Did you see caffe.cpp, the line among 287-308?

Comment: what `caffe.cpp`?? put links. I am sure.

Comment: @Shai   https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/tools/caffe.cpp

Comment: @ Shai   I save the output log file, and I analysed it. I found each batch has detected many classes,and they have some wrongs, I mean some output class number has a low score, so the detected video not show it, only showed the high score classes, so do you sure the detection_out has coordinates? Where can I see the definition of it?

Comment: @Shai  Did you see the 7 parameters in "Silence"? There has 2 parameters should be the same one: include=dict(phase=caffe_pb2.Phase.Value('TEST')),  but the output is different.